# How can I make a preset time limit for asyncio?

Tags: discord.py

I'm using asyncio for the command "offer". However, I am not sure how to make the command eligible for 30 minutes, then delete the response after the time is up. I'm not sure if there is a syntax error in my code either, but nothing was highlighted.

````
@bot.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Franchise Owner", "General Manager", "Head Coach")
async def offer(ctx, member:discord.Member):
  embed = discord.Embed(
  )
  embed.add_field(name="⌛ Incoming Offer", value=f"The <:DallasCowboys:788796627161710592> have offered {member}.")
  offer_sent = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  await ctx.member.send("You have been offered to the <:DallasCowboys:788796627161710592>. You have 30 minutes to accept/decline.")
  await offer_sent.asyncio.sleep(30)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your issue was you were sleeping on an embed variable so fixed that and allowed you to delete the message after.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Franchise Owner", "General Manager", "Head Coach")
async def offer(ctx, member:discord.Member):
  embed = discord.Embed(
  )
  embed.add_field(name="⌛ Incoming Offer", value=f"The <:DallasCowboys:788796627161710592> have offered {member}.")
  offer_sent = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  await ctx.member.send("You have been offered to the <:DallasCowboys:788796627161710592>. You have 30 minutes to accept/decline.")
  await asyncio.sleep(30) # wait 30 minutes
  await offer_sent.delete() # delete the offer_sent embed after time is up
```

I recommend using the [wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) reaction and setting it to timeout at 30 minutes.